# how can i use b-lazy plugin with html5 "picture" tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, plugins, jquery-plugins

i want to use **b-lazy plugin** with "picture" tag.
here default src attribute used with "data-arc" attribute. and src attribute used for lazy loading image..but how can i use this plugin picture tag...? b-lazy plugin support html5  "picture" and "img" tag.([this is support info link](https://www.drupal.org/project/blazy))but how can i implement this..
This is my html code:

here is b-lazy plugin link [B-lazy plugin](http://dinbror.dk/blog/blazy/)

```
 <picture class="b-lazy">
        <source
            media="(max-width: 767px)"
            srcset="imagepath/imgname.jpg">
        <source
            media="(max-width: 1024px)"
            srcset="imagepath/imgname.jpg">
        <source
            media="(max-width: 1920px)"
            srcset="imagepath/imgname.jpg">
        <source
            media="(max-width: 3840px)"
            srcset="imagepath/imgname.jpg">                 
        <img

            src="img/photos/h.jpg"
            data-src-small="" 
            alt="The Oslo Opera House">                             
    </picture>
```

This is my js code:

```
if ($("body").hasClass("page_id_images")) {
     //Global blazy module starts
     var bLazy = new Blazy({
          breakpoints: [{
                    width: 767, // max-width
                    src: 'data-src-small'
                     },
                     {
                    width: 1024, // max-width
                    src: 'data-src-medium'
                     },

                    {
                     width: 1920, // max-width
                     src: 'data-src-desktop'
                    },

                    {
                     width: 3840, // max-width
                     src: 'data-src-large'
                }],
         error: function(ele, msg) {

             var image = $(ele)[0];
             if (msg === 'missing') {
                 console.warn("Custom ERROR: ", image, " data-src is missing\n");
             } else if (msg === 'invalid') {
                 console.warn("Custom ERROR: ", image, " data-src is invalid\n");
             }
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

here is a answer for this question what i am trying to find out..

```
    <picture> 
    <source 
         media="(min-width: 650px)"
         data-srcset="image-650.jpg" /> 
    <source 
         media="(min-width: 465px)" 
         data-srcset="image-465.jpg" />
    <img class="b-lazy"
         data-src="default.jpg" />
</picture>
```